# Why doesn't CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes execute the memory release callback?

Tags: ios, macos, core-video

I create a buffer with CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes and pass a callback function as a parameter:

```
CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(NULL, imf.iWidth, imf.iHeight, pixelFormat, NULL, 0, 3, (void**)ppPlaneData, nPlaneWidth, nPlaneHeight, nPlaneBytesPerRow, LAVSinkPixelBufferReleasePlanarBytes, ppPlaneData, NULL, &buffer)
```

For some reason my callback LAVSinkPixelBufferReleasePlanarBytes is not called after I release the buffer with CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer).

However a different callback is called properly if I use CVPixelBufferCreateWithBytes function, but I want to use the planar data version.

Larger code snippet:

```
void LAVSinkPixelBufferReleasePlanarBytes(void* releaseRefCon, const void* dataPtr, size_t dataSize, size_t numberOfPlanes, const void* planeAddresses[])
{
  // This is never called
}
```

...
...

```
 size_t nPlaneSize[3];
 uint8_t** ppPlaneData = new uint8_t*[3];
 for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
    nPlaneSize[i] = nPlaneBytesPerRow[i] * nPlaneHeight[i];
    ppPlaneData[i] = new uint8_t[nPlaneSize[i]];
    memcpy(ppPlaneData[i], ppPlaneAddress[i], nPlaneSize[i]);
 }

 if (CVPixelBufferCreateWithPlanarBytes(NULL, imf.iWidth, imf.iHeight, pixelFormat, NULL, 0, 3, (void**)ppPlaneData, nPlaneWidth, nPlaneHeight, nPlaneBytesPerRow, LAVSinkPixelBufferReleasePlanarBytes, ppPlaneData, NULL, &buffer) != kCVReturnSuccess) break;

 const BOOL result = [adaptor appendPixelBuffer:buffer withPresentationTime:timestamp];
 CVPixelBufferRelease(buffer);
```

I found someone else asking the same question with much cleaner sample code:
http://prod.lists.apple.com/archives/cocoa-dev/2013/Nov/msg00177.html

But unfortunately there is no answer.

Comment: Can you post a more complete code snippet?

Comment: I've updated my post with more code.

Comment: Same problem here :(